# set programmatically image in Android BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android

I had a problem I'm programing my app in which I wants to use dynamically set the images from drawable.

means I want to use like: `flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.+my_variable+);` 
this is my code:

```
public class AlphabetAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private Context context;
  private final String[] alphabets;

public AlphabetAdapter(Context context, String[] alphabets) {

   this.context = context;
   this.alphabets = alphabets;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;
        if (convertView == null) {

                gridView = new View(context);
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_six_alphabets, null);
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setText(alphabets[position]);
        ImageView flag = (ImageView) gridView .findViewById(R.id.flag);
        String mobile = alphabets[position];

                if (mobile.equals("apple")) {
        flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);

            } else if (mobile.equals("ant")) {
                flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.ant);
            } else if (mobile.equals("aeroplane")) {
                flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.airplane);
            } else if (mobile.equals("alligator")) {
                flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.alligator);
            } else if (mobile.equals("arrow")) {
                flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
            } else {
                flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.arm);
            }

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
}
```

Comment: no one can not not do this ,because to retrieve wanted image from drawable folder, you must have to compare first. i.e. way you done is correct

Comment: where is `getCount` , `getItem` and  `getItemId`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
int i = context.getResources().
             getIdentifier(mobile, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
flag.setImageResource(i);
```

Above code: will 1st fetch the id for mobile from drawable which is equivalent to R.drawable.{mobile} for example if mobile is "ant" code will return id for drawable ant i.e. R.drawable.ant and in 2nd line we will use this id and set Image Resource..

Comment: hi prashant,   thanks for answering, i tried this code but problem is  this.getPackageName() because it is not activity class

Comment: Try using context.getPackageName() instead of this.getPackageName()

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your array for int type.
Replace this:

```
String[] alphabets;
```

For this:

```
int[] alphabets;
```

And in your code you can use this line:

```
rh.imageviewLeft.setBackgroundResource(alphabets[position]);
```

Note: In the array that you send fill it for example with this:

```
int [] img = new int [] { R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.ant }
```

And add in your Adapter this:

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return alphabets.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return alphabets[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}
```

I hope help, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..
in your activity

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> ThemeId = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
.....
        ThemeId.clear();
        ThemeId.put("apple", R.drawable.apple);
        ThemeId.put("ant", R.drawable.ant);
        ThemeId.put("aeroplane", R.drawable.aeroplane);
        ThemeId.put("alligator", R.drawable.alligator);
        ThemeId.put("arrow", R.drawable.arrow);
        ThemeId.put("arm", R.drawable.arm);

}
```

//in base adapter

```
 import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class AlphabetAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private final String[] alphabets;

        public AlphabetAdapter(Context context, String[] alphabets) {

            this.context = context;
            this.alphabets = alphabets;

        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View gridView;
            if (convertView == null) {

                gridView = new View(context);
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_six_alphabets, null);
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                textView.setText(alphabets[position]);
                ImageView flag = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
                String mobile = alphabets[position];


                    flag.setImageResource(YourActivity.ThemeId.get(mobile));


            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return alphabets.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return alphabets[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi umesh, thanks for comment but i wants to use like flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.+my_variable+); instead of flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);